# If a statement is fulfilled add rows in a new Excel file

Tags: python, excel

This works nicely, but I want it to write on an Excel file, preferably using xlwt module. Can anyone please help  me out?

```
def db():
    import xlrd
    import xlwt
    disbook = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xls')
    mapping_table = disbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    mapping_table_col_len = mapping_table.nrows     # for allgo
    allgo = disbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet2')   # for allgo
    allgo_col_len = allgo.nrows                     # for allgo
    for i in range(allgo_col_len):
        x = allgo.cell_value(i, 1)
        counter = 0
        book = xlwt.Workbook()
        sheet1 = book.add_sheet('sheet1')
        for j in range(mapping_table_col_len):
            y = mapping_table.cell_value(j, 13)
            if x==y:
                z1 = str(mapping_table.row_values(j, start_colx=0, end_colx=None))
                counter = counter+1
                if counter>1:
                    break
                print(z1)
```

Comment: Won't sheet1.write(...) serve the purpose. Check the xlwt API documentation:https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966

Comment: Yes, I visited it and also tried to use its write attribute but in my case i fail to implement it. z1 variable prints exactly what i want but how to write this output in an Excel sheet is a problem. Hopes, one of you suggest me or edit the code. I know, only few lines to be edited but I am trying since last 4-5 days but failed.